# Markdown editor and preview not working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, markdown

I have these two plugins installed currently:

1. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17254-markdown-editor
2. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793-markdown

none of these works.

I have googled this problem and found many people are facing the same issue.
But a few solutions that I found, did not work for me

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Please help

Answer (score 95):

Have encountered the same after updating Android Studio to Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (and now the Bumblebee 2021.1.1).

Decide not to wait anymore, did some search and found that this is happened because the latest version of Markdown by JetBrains requires Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF), but it is not bundled with the default runtime for the IDE.

Update the runtime to the one with JCEF in the following steps could solve this issue:

1. Select **Help** > **Find Action** from the Android Studio menu.
2. Enter "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE" and select it from the suggestion list.
3. Select the runtime that comes with JCEF support as shown in the image below:
   [image]
4. Click **OK** and restart the IDE.

**Disclaimer** Apply the change at your own risk since there is a statement claiming that changing the runtime may cause unexpected problems. Will again update this post if I have encountered any other issues after this has been set.

**Update:**
Joachim Schuster has written a detailed [article](https://joachimschuster.de/posts/android-studio-fix-markdown-plugin/) to explain on this and the steps to fix it.

Comment: Answer is still valid in June 2023 on Android Studio Flamingo, except the 11's become 17's.

Comment: Using a 17.*-jcef runtime with Android Studio Giraffe and I cannot even open .MD files in text mode. So annoying.

Comment: still help with Android Studio Hedgehog

Comment: `GPU process restarts too many times and seems to be unstable. Try to restart IDE or disable GPU acceleration completely.` Apparently changing to other Java versions is causing GPU error in M1 MacOs.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html Don't change runtime unless you know what you're doing, because it can cause issues. mine is broken.

Comment: @FaizanAnwerAliRupani unfortunately not just on M1 Macs, also on Intel based... 

Comment: With Android Studio Hedgehog the solution described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317401/Too-many-restarts-of-GPU-process-adding-a-development-build-of-jar#focus=Comments-27-8806472.0-0) worked for me